# Android Emulator crashes in MacOS 13.3 Intel Chip

Tags: macos, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, qemu

I ran emulator from command-line, because In android studio it just hangs immediately after I ran it, it process is listed in Activity Monitor but window is open.

Here is the log, when I ran it from CMD,

```
WARNING: engine selection is deprecated.
INFO    | Found systemPath /Users/icebit-lab-01/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-31/google_apis/x86_64/
INFO    | Storing crashdata in: /tmp/android-icebit-imac3/emu-crash.db, detection is enabled
INFO    | Duplicate loglines will be removed, if you wish to see each indiviudal line launch with the -log-nofilter flag.
WARNING | Please update the emulator to one that supports the feature(s): Vulkan
WARNING | Running on a system with less than 6 logical cores. Setting number of virtual cores to 1
WARNING | cannot add library /Users/icebit-lab-01/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/qemu/darwin-x86_64/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.dylib: failed
INFO    | Sending adb public key [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 icebit-imac3@unknown]
INFO    | added library /Users/icebit-lab-01/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.dylib
HVF error: HV_ERROR
qemu-system-x86_64: failed to initialize HVF: Invalid argument
Failed to open the hax module
No accelerator found.
qemu-system-x86_64: failed to initialize HAX: Operation not supported by device
```

The command which I executed,

`./emulator -no-snapshot-load @Pixel_6_Pro_API_31 -engine qemu2 -show-kernel -read-only`